# How do i acces a link from array in a random order without repeating the last one chosen?

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, random

```
  let urlArray = [
            "link",
            "link2",
            "link3",
        ];
        function randomUrl() {    

            let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * urlArray.length);
            let newUrl = urlArray[randomNumber];
            let visitedGame = document.referrer;
            setTimeout(function () {
                //if the previous link is not the same as the one generated access the generated link
                if (newUrl !== visitedGame)  {
                    window.location = newUrl;
               //access the next link from the array
                 } else{
                    
                 }
            }, 3000);
        }
        randomUrl();
```

I have this code that i'm stuck at.

So what i'm trying to do:

On some click ( that is not in the code right here, but it works ) i access this function. When i click that button, i need to generate a random link from this array, but without repeating the last accesed in the browser. so without the previous url that was accesed. I tried getting the document. referrer but it seems it doesn't work. Please help :(

Comment: when you say `the last (link) accesed in the browser` you mean the current page url?

Comment: No, the one before that

Comment: in that case, `document.referrer` should be the right approach. What exactly does not work?

Comment: also, why do you need setTimeout?

Comment: That is because i need to wait 3 sec and after that acess the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively call the function until you generate a Url that is not visited last.

See code below:

```
let urlArray = [
  "link",
  "link2",
  "link3",
];

function randomUrl() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * urlArray.length);
  let newUrl = urlArray[randomNumber];
  let visitedGame = document.referrer;
  if (newUrl === visitedGame) {
    // Recursively try generating another random Url if same as last visited
    randomUrl();
  } else {
    // Visit the new Url after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location = newUrl;
    }, 3000);
  }
}

randomUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last `link` from the array. In this example splice is used. But in your code you can make a copy of original array and use that to randomly access the link, and after accessing it remove the link from the array

```js
let urlArray = [
  "link",
  "link2",
  "link3",
];

function randomUrl() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * urlArray.length);
  let newUrl = urlArray[randomNumber];
  console.log(newUrl);
  urlArray.splice(randomNumber, 1);
  console.log(urlArray)
}
randomUrl();
```

Comment: Since the OP is trying to navigate to the generated URL (from his snippet), I think this solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need always the same list without delete link, you can save the last index of url then don't use it for the next step like:

```js
let urlArray = [
  "link",
  "link2",
  "link3",
];
let index;

function randomUrl() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * urlArray.length);
  if (index !== randomNumber) {
    let newUrl = urlArray[randomNumber];
    console.log(newUrl);
    index = randomNumber;
  } else {
    randomUrl();
  }
}
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
randomUrl();
```

The same link can be used multiple times but not repeated the next time

Comment: Since the OP is trying to navigate to the generated URL (from his snippet), I think this solution won't work.

Comment: The method work, it's just to change how catch the index, he don't say nothing about that i just tell an idea :D